# difference between .so.0 and .so.0.0.0 files

Tags: linux

Im using a market data source implementation that contains .so.0 files. However these are 'soft links' **to** actual .so.0.0.0 files. Why is this done?

When I try to copy these .so.0 links, it ends up copying an exact replica of the .so.0.0.0 file but with a .so.0 prefix.

Added comment:

so I have a libfoo.so file, and it is being accessed by java through jni. This libfoo.so file is actually a soft link that points to libfoo.so.0.0.0 What happens if I don't have libfoo.so. How does java/or any other compiled code, figure out that libfoo.so.0.0.0 if the shared object to use?

Comment: what is a 'market data source'? What are these files? What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: I believe that _"market data source"_ is probably a COTS data connection solution of some sort that ships its implementation in a shared object file, but I'm not a Java programmer ;)

Comment: This is not related to java - your so files are found by a platform-dependent application, for instance `ld` on Linux.

Comment: Please don't down vote just because you don't know the answer...

Answer (score 10):

This is so programs can bind to either any version of libfoo that has the same interface (I want the latest updates to libfoo), or bind to a specific version (I want stability and only the exact version I tested against).

Comment: so I have a libfoo.so file, and it is being accessed by java through jni. This libfoo.so file is actually a soft link that points to libfoo.so.0.0.0

What happens if I don't have libfoo.so. How does java/or any other compiled code, figure out that libfoo.so.0.0.0 if the shared object to use?

Comment: If you have libfoo.so.0.0.0 you should always have libfoo.so.0 and libfoo.so, this is part of how libtool works; if it doesn't exist, they're generating the libraries wrong

Comment: @user242591 it doesn't, but if you have `libfoo.so.0.0.0` you are almost guaranteed to have `libfoo.so` and `libfoo.so.0`, and if you don't that's a problem for a lot of programs other than yours. How much of a problem and how many programs depends on the library's popularity so if it's something like SDL then a lot of programs rely on that so if you don't have it there's a good chance stuff will break, but if you are missing `libsidplay2.so.1` how many programs rely on that (not many I think, it's a library to play C64 sound files, although though maybe some (my?) media player relies on it)

Answer (score 7):

The .0 and .0.0.0 files exist so that versioning can happen:

- foo.0 represents the .0 version of a library.  All .0 versions of the library will use the same interface, but there may be different implementations.  (Hopefully, the later implementations will have fewer bugs than the earlier ones.)
- foo.0.0.0 represents a specific implementation of the .0 version.

It's not useful, now, to have the soft-link.  But here's what could happen:

The programmer of foo finds a bug in his library.  He releases foo.0.0.1.  And foo.0 now links to foo.0.0.1.  Then two things happen:

- All files that link to foo.0 will automatically update to foo.0.0.1.
- All files that link to foo.0.0.0 will continue to use the old foo.0.0.0

Comment: Extend this a few levels further and you can require an exact version match by linking against `libfoo.0.0.0` or any matching interface version with `libfoo.0` or any version at all with `libfoo`.

Comment: Apologise for the basic question, but how is this linking specified. How can I specify that jni should use libfoo.so and not libfoo.so.0.0.0?

Comment: Hihi, coder zambesi.  Sadly, Java documents are not much help: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String) says "The manner in which a library name is mapped to the actual system library is system dependent."  There might be some help at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010503/how-to-debug-a-java-system-loadlibrary-error-in-linux  Good luck.