# .Net Core 3.1 - loading native library with extension .so.0 failed

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

I'm migrating project from mono to .NET Core and I'm using sqlite library.

Following code works as expected in Mono, but not in dotnet:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sqlite version: " + Sqlite.LibVersionNumber());
        }
    }

    public static class Sqlite
    {
        const string LibraryPath = "sqlite3";

        [DllImport(LibraryPath, EntryPoint = "sqlite3_libversion_number", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int LibVersionNumber();
    }
```

Problem is, that in /usr/lib I have libsqlite3.so.0
If I rename (or create symlink in /usr/lib) to libsqlite3.so (without .0) everything works correctly in .NET Core.

Is there some switch to load also .so.0 libraries? Is it bug? Or expected feature?

Comment: Why are you explicitly trying to load the library in this way?

Comment: This is minimalistic example from sqlite-net ORM. And I was using it on Linux/Mono for 5 years. What is alternative?

Comment: There is no mention of requiring these shenanigans on the [sqlite-net GitHub](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net). Considering you mention Mono it's my guess that your code is extremely old - you should update it to reference the latest version of the libraries it requires, and you will have far fewer problems with .NET Core (or in general).

Comment: This code is taken directly from sqlite-net ORM https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs line 4260. Sqlite-net is not working with build in libsqlite3.so.0 library.

Comment: Are you using the **full** class from there, or did you only pull out the part that you've shown in your question? Because the full class has various `#ifdefs` that change how it works based on the platform it's compiled for. If you don't have the same, the code will not work.

Comment: I know how to compile or use sqlite-net and I can make it work in Net Core via symlink, adding .so library to my app or using sqlite raw nuget package. Question is about using platform native libraries which has different policy in Net Core and I think It is not standard because if Linux app require  .so should also accept .so.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should allways have the .so and it should allways be a link.

[How Do so (Shared Object) Filenames Work?](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/shared-object-filenames)

[difference between .so.0 and .so.0.0.0 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003915/difference-between-so-0-and-so-0-0-0-files)